# Group specific range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a Macro to select and group a certain amount of cells, a simple example picture is included below. The only thing that should determine the range is `column A`.

Let's say the active cell is somewhere between `row 2 and row 13`, the Macro should be able to find out that `row 1 and row 14` are the boundaries of that range because of the presence of values in column A and so creating and selecting a range going from `row 2 till row 13`.
I tried to loop through the cells going down to find the first row with an active value in `column A`, have a general idea how it should work but struggling to create a working code :)

```
    Dim StartCell, EindCell As Range
    Dim teller As Integer
    Dim teller2 As Integer

teller = 0
Do While Selection.Offset(teller, 0).Value = ""
    teller = teller - 1
Loop
Selection.Offset(teller, 0).Select
Set StartCell = ActiveCell

teller2 = 0
Do While Selection.Offset(teller, 0).Value = ""
    teller = teller + 1
Loop
Selection.Offset(teller, 0).Select

    Set EindCell = ActiveCell
    Range(StartCell, EindCell).Select
```

[image]

Comment: Updated code so far included above.

Comment: I've posted a new question with a few extra implementations and extras so this one with the active title wasn't really "relevant" anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
Sub Group()


Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rstart As Long, Rend As Long
Dim R As Long

R = ActiveCell.Row
If Len(Cells(R, "A").Value) Then R = R + 1
Rstart = R
Do Until Len(Cells(Rstart - 1, "A").Value)
    Rstart = Rstart - 1
Loop
Rend = R
R = Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
Do Until Len(Cells(Rend + 1, "A").Value)
    Rend = Rend + 1
    If Rend = R Then Exit Do
Loop

Set Rng = Range(Cells(Rstart, "H"), Cells(Rend, "H"))
```

*Source:*

[Calculating sum and grouping of dynamic range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48222880/calculating-sum-and-grouping-of-dynamic-range)